# Copying and pasting data from an internet post to the R console

Tags: r

I am trying to import (or copy and paste) the dataset on this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/226956/67822) into the R console, using these commands:

```
library(psych)
mat <- "dimnames<-"(as.matrix(read.clipboard()), NULL)
```

and

```
dat = read.table(stdin(), header=TRUE)
```

with error messages.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Your second line of code appears to be copied in error, and the link you provided has no code.

Comment: @Tim When I click on the link, I see a data set in the form of a table. I am not trying to copy code - the issue is how to get into R datasets that appear on online posts.

Comment: You can use `psych::read.clipboard.tab`, but the problem is that the fields of the data you are copying do not have a unique separator. As a result, that will only return a data.frame with one column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a one-off copy and paste, you might want to try something like this:

```
df <- read.table(header=T,text="Strength              ChangenInstigators     GroupB     GroupC
Communication         300                    100        122
Productivity          200                    212        500
ConflictResolution   150                    157        130
Vision                216                    256        233
Personnel             350                    300        222")
```

The reason why you're probably getting errors is because one header "Change Instigators" has a space so its trying to be read as 2 columns. Furthermore, "Conflict resolution" has a space in it as well so it is also being read in as 2 columns. If you remove these two spaces it should work.

Comment: I saw the space in "Change Instigators", but I completely missed it in "Conflict Resolution". Thank you.